# Navigation of Viewport not possible to do

Tags: 3d-view, camera, navigation

I just downloaded and installed Blender, but I'm stuck with navigating the scene.

I can't rotate or interact with the scene.

[image]

When I click <kbd>LMB</kbd> and drag, it doesn't rotate the scene. This happens instead:

[image]

I don't know how valuable this will be, but this is what I got after going into Preferences:

[image]

Comment: Use the middle mouse button, click to orbit, scroll to zoom, shift click to pan

Comment: ohh wow, thank you, i never tried scroll wheel because i haven't used like this as a navigation before !!!  thank you

Answer (score 0):

The dashed rectangle created is the "Box Select" area. Pressing LMB and dragging allows Box Select to select all objects inside the area when the LMB is released. In itself it is a useful tool so remember it.

If you have a mouse with a scroll wheel, you can navigate the 3D Viewport using the wheel. Scrolling the wheel allows for zoom in/out. Pressing the wheel and moving the mouse rotates the Viewport. Mouse cursor position is important when starting this as it affects how the navigation is handled. Holding SHIFT while pressing the scroll wheel 'pan's the Viewport instead of rotating it.

You can also navigate using the NUMPAD keys 2, 4, 6, and 8. There are also other ways listed in the Blender manual.

It can be tricky sometimes as you are usually more focused on the project rather than the mouse or keyboard actions. But getting used to the navigation is important as it will help a lot in future work. Hope this helps!